# How to detect and find checkboxes in a form using Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have several images for which I need to do OMR by detecting checkboxes using computer vision.

I'm using `findContours` to draw contours only on the checkboxes in scanned document. But the algorithm extracts each and every contours of the text.

```py
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import argparse, imutils, cv2, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 75, 200)

im_test = [blurred, cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0), cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 5), cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)]
im_thresh = [ cv2.threshold(i, 127, 255, 0)  for i in im_test ]
im_thresh_0 = [i[1] for i in im_thresh ]
im_cnt = [cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0] for thresh in im_thresh_0]

im_drawn = [cv2.drawContours(image.copy(), contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1) for contours in im_cnt]

plt.imshow(im_drawn[0])
plt.show()
```

Input Image:

[image]

Comment: You can checkout my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801071/9605907 for the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. **Obtain binary image.** [Load the image](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/), [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html), [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering), and [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) to obtain a binary black/white image.
2. **Remove small noise particles.** [Find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) and filter using [contour area filtering](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) to remove noise.
3. **Repair checkbox horizontal and vertical walls.** This step is optional but in the case where the checkboxes may be damaged, we repair the walls for easier detection. The idea is to create a [rectangular kernel](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element) then perform [morphological operations](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html).
4. **Detect checkboxes.** From here we find contours, obtain the [bounding rectangle coordinates](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect), and filter using [shape approximation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp) + aspect ratio. The idea is that a checkbox is essentially a square so its contour dimensions should be within a range.

---

Input image `->` Binary image

[image]
[image]

Detected checkboxes highlighted in green

[image]

> Checkboxes: 52

Another input image `->` Binary image

[image]
[image]

Detected checkboxes highlighted in green

[image]

> Checkboxes: 2

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and filter using contour area filtering to remove noise
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
AREA_THRESHOLD = 10
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < AREA_THRESHOLD:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)

# Repair checkbox horizontal and vertical walls
repair_kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
repair = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel1, iterations=1)
repair_kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
repair = cv2.morphologyEx(repair, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel2, iterations=1)

# Detect checkboxes using shape approximation and aspect ratio filtering
checkbox_contours = []
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(repair, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.035 * peri, True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    aspect_ratio = w / float(h)
    if len(approx) == 4 and (aspect_ratio >= 0.8 and aspect_ratio <= 1.2):
        cv2.rectangle(original, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
        checkbox_contours.append(c)

print('Checkboxes:', len(checkbox_contours))
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('repair', repair)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks. But when i tried the code on the real data it still doesn't worked. Tried tweaking the threshold and also the len of approx.  Input image: https://imgur.com/LrzYXga

Comment: It's working for me, try change `threshold_max_area` to 3000. I added the output with this new input image

Comment: @nathancy, this looks great. Yet, is there any way to recognize if a box is checked?

Comment: @Kalaschnik yes same question did you find any way for that?

Comment: @gig With the assumption that the size of the checkbox is the same, an idea to recognize if a box is already checked is: 1) obtain checkbox contour 2) to count the number of white pixels (maybe `cv2.countNonZero`) and compare it to either a baseline value or just compare pixel percentage. So if say if 80% pixels are white then its not checked otherwise it is checked

Answer (score 3):

Well... Are the checkboxes always in that region of the image? The checkboxes Always maintain the same size area on the image?

If yes, you can run findContours only in that region of the image...

Or maybe the Template Matching with Multiple Objects, example from OpenCV docs: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: each document has checkbox in different region some of them have horizontally, vertically or combined aligned along with text. Also, the solution i'm trying to built needs to be templateless.

Comment: Here is an example of a shape detector, you can use the example to detect only squares (your chekboxes):

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Hope it helps...

Comment: already referred to that example and lots of thread in stackoverflow. But still im not able to find out how to avoid text regions.