# How to use OpenCV to detect a checkbox that intersects a line in a document

Tags: python, opencv, checkbox, detection

I have successfully used code to detect checkboxes in documents, following the base case similar to:

[How to detect/find checkbox contours using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763858/how-to-detect-find-checkbox-contours-using-opencv)

It is working well, however it fails whenever a box touches a line on one of its sides, which occurs fairly frequently in my use case. I have included two examples, one original and one is the image after being processed with canny.

[Checkbox intersecting line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG4zq.png)
[Checkbox after canny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Chqu.png)

Is there a general method for separating two overlapping contours, or some other method I could use to detect the box that has such an overlap?

Comment: Use morphology to remove horizontal lines longer than the box width.

Comment: Do a connected component on the image you linked (
Checkbox intersecting line). That gives you a square in the middle of the image which you can select that based on it's height/width ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use morphology to remove most of the long line using Python/OpenCV as follows. Use morphology close to detect the line. Then invert the line and add it back to the input image to write over the line with white.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('box_line.png')

# do morphology to find long horizontal lines using a horizontal kernel longer than the width of the box
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (80,1))
line = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 1)

# invert line
line = (255-line)

# add inverted line to image
result = cv2.add(img, line)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("line_removed.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.imshow("line", line)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Use the above to preprocess your image and then use your other code to extract the box via contours.