# Multiple choice scanner [hard version with a lot of text], please give me some guidance

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, opencv, edge-detection

You probably saw or heard a lot of multiple-choice scanners using cv2.

However, my paper is like this [image]

There are a lot of words mixing in it, therefore, after resizing images, it's all most impossible for me to find contours of the square box. Words existing in the page disrupted this process.

Personally, I think it would be better to take a better picture.
Anyway the point here is, I lost, please give me any guidance, appreciate any detail helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to detect the small boxes on the sheet. [See this question to know how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801070/detect-checkboxes-from-a-form-using-opencv-python/62809396#62809396)

Then you will need to get the horizontal lines on which these boxes are present for each question(take lines of height > 1 pixel).

Then find the position of the box(wrt other boxes) moving from left to right on the horizontal line which is filled(have a tick). Thus, for that question, the box number is the answer selected.

Comment: Hey, trying working on it, however, since I take picture through a webcam, I need to resacle, scan the document, erase outliner and make a bird view. Then the image quality decreases to an extend that it can not recognize the square checkbox anymore. Any advises ?

Comment: @Chau, My guess, try not to increase or decrease size of sheet in terms of pixels while rescaling nd making the bird view. If in one image, size of sheet is 800, 600 then keep it that only and if in second image, size of sheet is 200,200 then keep it this only. Don't generalise them to a same size.