# Python Opencv: Finding boxes in interrupted picture

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to find rectangles in the figures.

I can find them when outside of the boxes are not interrupted with writings with the code below. However when the box is interrupted with handwriting I cannot find it, that is the part that I need help.

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

image = cv2.imread('original_image.jpeg')

blur = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image, 11, 21)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        print(approx)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        if(w > 10 and h > 10):
            print(x,y,w,h)
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,255,12),2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.imshow('image', image)
```

Original Image:

[image: Original IMage]

Interrupted Image with handwriting:

[image: Interrupted IMage]

Boxes found on original image:

[image: Result of the code with original picture]

How can I find the box in the interrupted picture?

Comment: Try thresholding the image wrt BGR colors. Everything below (20, 20, 20) colour value will be 0 and above it will be 255. It will remove everything in the blue ink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use my answer which is a solution to find all the checkboxes from a given form to get the boxes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801071/9605907
The steps are basically like this.

1. binarise the image
2. find horizontal lines
3. find vertical lines
4. combine them
5. get Connected components using `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats`

I tried running the code with your input image and this was the result I got,

#### Output binary image:

[image: binary image]

#### Output after doing connected component analysis:

[image: output image]

You can get the code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801071/9605907).

Comment: One morequestion for you=)  what is your python opencv version?

Comment: @s900n Happy to help :D. My OpenCV version is 3.4.4