# Checkbox detection opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I have been trying to detect the checkboxes. Though I was able to detect the square contours in other images I was not able to get the contours for this particular image. Please help me detect the checkboxes.

Input image:
[image: Input Image]

This is my code,

```
for myfile in files:
    image=cv2.imread(myfile)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (180,60), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #apply otsu's threshold
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        #setting up threshold values
    threshold_max_area = 300
    threshold_min_area = 10
 #finding contours in the image
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
#getting the coordinates for each checkbox
    count=0
    centers=[]
    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.035 * peri, True)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        aspect_ratio = w / float(h)
        area = cv2.contourArea(c) 
        if len(approx) == 4 and area < threshold_max_area and area > threshold_min_area and (aspect_ratio >= 0.9 and aspect_ratio <= 1.1):
            centers.append([x,y,x+w,y+h]) 
        count=count+1
    print(centers)
    
cv2.imshow(" ",image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: You can get an answer from previously asked questions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763858/how-to-detect-find-checkbox-contours-using-opencv).

Comment: @Abhishek The link you mentioned is fine when your checkbox does not have a tick mark in it. In my case, there is a tick mark as a result of which I'm not able to detect the square contour.

Comment: What about template matching on binary image? You can search for the rectangle if you know the size of the boxes.

Answer (score 6):

This is one way to solve it.

#### Step 1: Binarisation

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

### reading input image
image_path='test_sample.jpg'
image=cv2.imread(image_path)

### converting BGR to Grayscale
gray_scale=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

### Binarising image
th1,img_bin = cv2.threshold(gray_scale,180,225,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Binary image:

[image: binary image]

#### Step 2: Finding horizontal and vertical lines

```py
### defining kernels

lWidth = 2
lineMinWidth = 15

kernal1 = np.ones((lWidth,lWidth), np.uint8)
kernal1h = np.ones((1,lWidth), np.uint8)
kernal1v = np.ones((lWidth,1), np.uint8)

kernal6 = np.ones((lineMinWidth,lineMinWidth), np.uint8)
kernal6h = np.ones((1,lineMinWidth), np.uint8)
kernal6v = np.ones((lineMinWidth,1), np.uint8)

### finding horizontal lines
img_bin_h = cv2.morphologyEx(~img_bin, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernal1h) # bridge small gap in horizonntal lines
img_bin_h = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin_h, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal6h) # kep ony horiz lines by eroding everything else in hor direction
```

Horizontal Lines:

[image: horizontal lines]

```py
## detect vert lines
img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(~img_bin, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernal1v)  # bridge small gap in vert lines
img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin_v, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal6v)# kep ony vert lines by eroding everything else in vert direction
```

Vertical Lines:

[image: vertical lines]

#### Step 3: combining horizontal and vertical lines

```py
def fix(img):
    img[img>127]=255
    img[img<127]=0
    return img
img_bin_final = fix(fix(img_bin_h)|fix(img_bin_v))
```

Combined binary output:

[image: binary final]

#### Step 4: Find rectangles using Connected Components

```py
### getting labels
ret, labels, stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(~img_bin_final, connectivity=8, ltype=cv2.CV_32S)

### drawing recangles for visualisation
for x,y,w,h,area in stats[2:]:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
```

Final output:
[image: final outptu]

Comment: @SharathChanderP Please accept the answer, if you were able to solve the issue. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

For extracting information from checkboxes, we should be performing a set of morphologic operations. These include identifying the edges by detecting horizontal, vertical lines and contours filtering.

Do check the detailed blog post here: https://nanonets.com/blog/checkbox-detection. We had mentioned different techniques on how we can extract checkboxes using CV and deep learning techniques.

Code snippet for edge detection, contour filtering.

```
# set min width to detect horizontal lines

line_min_width = 15

# kernel to detect horizontal lines
kernal_h = np.ones((1,line_min_width), np.uint8)

# kernel to detect vertical lines
kernal_v = np.ones((line_min_width,1), np.uint8)

# horizontal kernel on the image
img_bin_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal_h)

# verical kernel on the image
img_bin_v = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernal_v)


# combining the image

img_bin_final=img_bin_h|img_bin_v

# contour filtering 

_, labels, stats,_ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(~img_bin_final, connectivity=8, ltype=cv2.CV_32S)

for x,y,w,h,area in stats[2:]:
    cv2.rectangle(image_array,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

Image.fromarray(image_array).show()
```