# How to detect a ticked checkbox and extract the text associated to it from an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I have PDFs consisting of images of forms. I want to apply OCR and OMR on this images to extract the required data. I want to detect ticked checkboxes and extract the associated data to those checkboxes from these images. However, the current code is not able to detect the contours of the ticked checkbox.

I am using `findcontours` to find contours and make bounding boxes around the checkboxes. This code is inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763858/how-to-detect-and-find-checkboxes-in-a-form-using-python-opencv). However, it is not able to detect the contours of the checkbox that is ticked. Here is the code and the image of the area in the form where I am applying the code.

[Image of the region of the form with checkboxes and associated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10ruZ.png)

```
gray = x_gray.copy() # Copy of the Grayscale image shared in this post 
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and filter using contour area filtering to remove noise
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
AREA_THRESHOLD = 100
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < AREA_THRESHOLD:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)

# Repair checkbox horizontal and vertical walls
repair_kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
repair = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel1, iterations=1)
repair_kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
repair = cv2.morphologyEx(repair, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel2, iterations=1)

# Detect checkboxes using shape approximation and aspect ratio filtering
checkbox_contours = []
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(repair, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.035 * peri, True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    aspect_ratio = w / float(h)
    if len(approx) == 4 and (aspect_ratio >= 0.8 and aspect_ratio <= 1.2):
        cv2.rectangle(gray, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3) #original
        checkbox_contours.append(c)

print('Checkboxes:', len(checkbox_contours))
```

I have tried various values of the parameter `AREA_THRESHOLD`  ranging from 10 - 200. However, I'm still not getting the expected result.

It would be really helpful if someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Look at your threshold image to see if the checkboxes are showing distinctly